# Geocoding Addresses - Error when selecting Address Locator to use

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

I'm running into some issues with ArcMap 10.3.1 when trying to use the geocoding tool to geocode a table of addresses from an .xls file. I've added my table into the Table of Contents, right clicked and chose "Geocode Addresses...". From here, the "Choose an Address Locator to use" dialog box appears. Our group uses a specific address location "Composite_Prod", which I've added by clicking the "Add" button and selecting it from our GIS Server (See screenshot. Everyone else in the office has no problem with this address locator). But, when I click "OK", the error below displays:

"Error: The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'GDB_Items'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly"

I have no idea where "GDB_Items" came from and at which point this table was selected as an input.

[image]
[image]